# SAge Pay Curl and Couldn't resolve host

Tags: php, curl

Our e-commerce site has been going years without and issue connecting to sagepaye. Recently once or twice a day we get the curl error 'Couldn't resolve host' here is the curl request.

```
    $logger = Logger::getIntance();
    $logger->log($vsppost, Zend_Log::INFO);

    set_time_limit( 60 );                                                            
    $output = array();                                                               
    $output['Status'] = "FAIL";

    $curlsession = curl_init();                                                      

    curl_setopt( $curlsession, CURLOPT_URL, Config::Get( 'ProtxRegistrationURL' ) );
    curl_setopt( $curlsession, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0 );
    curl_setopt( $curlsession, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
    curl_setopt( $curlsession, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $vsppost );
    curl_setopt( $curlsession, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
    curl_setopt( $curlsession, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30 );
    curl_setopt( $curlsession, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE );
    curl_setopt( $curlsession, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2 );

    $rawresponse = curl_exec( $curlsession );
    $_SESSION["rawresponse"] = $rawresponse;

    $logger->log(str_ireplace(chr(13).chr(10), ', ', $rawresponse), Zend_Log::INFO);
```

The logging shows the data is good. In fact I can see the same purchase request made an hour later and working.

The server is not under heavy load and there seems to have been no connection issues.

Any ideas as to the problem or how to create a test script to locate the issue. Is this really a dns lookup issue or some curl problem.

Answer (score -1):

I currently have the same issue and so far it seems to be tracked down to some incompatibility with the local DNS cache servers performing the lookup to the SagePay servers with ipv6 lookup.

I have 3 methods that mitigate this while the investigation is continuing:

1) request that curl only performs a ipv4 lookup:

```
curl_setopt( $curlsession, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE , CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4 );
```

2) hard code the SagePay host record into /etc/hosts
 - not great/advised at all, as if they change ip address at all then this will be outdated and pointing to the wrong location.

3) You could try using other DNS cache servers e.g. Googles DNS servers do not seem to have this issue ( have not experienced this issue while using them )